# Magento: Import product prices for an additional website?

Tags: magento, csv

I have a Magento installation, with two websites on it:

- Retail (default)
- Trade

Currently all the prices have been imported as default and so the prices are set the same on both websites. I now need to import the lower prices just for the trade website.

I know this can be done manually per product, but how do I go about importing these prices (with their SKU's so that they only apply to the trade store?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing a Product Export first so you can see all of the columns that are used.  Locate a SKU from your Trade store and see what the values are for that column.

You should see a column called `_product_websites`.  In my installation, this column has "base" in it.  On yours it will probably say "base" and "trade" (whatever you specified for your website code).  You can sort by this column in Excel or other spreadsheet software and remove all of the rows that just have "base" in it so you're left with "trade".  Now you can update your prices, save the sheet and re-import your file.

hth

Comment: I know exactly what you mean wit this suggestion, the only issue is that I have products in BOTH websites simultaneously. So if I upload one with just 'trade' in the websites column, it will make it no longer available for the retail site.

Comment: Duplicate all of the entries and put `base` in the `_product_websites` column for one set and `trade` in the other set.  Then you can change the prices for the store that you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply follow the following Magento blog post:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-prices-in-magento-in-easier-faster-way/

Just you need to add store_id filter in following method as:

```
function _updatePrices($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newPrice       = $data[1];
    $storeId        = $data[2];
    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();
 
    $sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped
                SET  cped.value = ?
            WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
            AND cped.entity_id = ?
            AND store_id = ?";
    $connection->query($sql, array($newPrice, $attributeId, $productId, $storeId));
}
```

Of course you need to use third column of prices.csv for store_id.
Let me know if that helps.